# Reload xml data from html every x seconds

Tags: html, xml, parsing, reload

I've wrote some code in order to parse and display to my html some content from an .xml file that I've created.
Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function loadXMLDoc(dname)
 {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
 xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {
 xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
 xhttp.send();
 return xhttp.responseXML;
 }

</script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("variables.xml");

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Light1")[0].childNodes[0];
txt=x.nodeValue;
document.write(txt);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is working properly, now all I want is to check every x seconds (lets says 1000msec) if the value of the xml has changed. In other ways load the content of the xml every x seconds..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `setInterval()` function to run your script every x milliseconds. For 1000 milliseconds, it will look like this:

```
setInterval(function() {

    xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("variables.xml");

    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Light1")[0].childNodes[0];
    txt=x.nodeValue;
    document.write(txt);

}, 1000);
```

Comment: thanx Colin but that didnt worked..Not its not loading anything

Comment: oops sorry!its working!!But maybe i have a problem with the cookies now..even if the value is "Light1" is changed the value in the browser is not changing. If i try it with the live preview at Dreamweaver the value changes after 1 second..